# Problem on finding the number of cosets of subspace in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to solve the following entrance exam question

If $W$ is a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over the field of residue classes modulo $5$ such that $dim V = 5$, $dim W = 2$. Then I have to find the total number of cosets of $W$ in $V$.

I am able to find out the basis of cosets of subspace in a vector space of polynomials and $R^n$ (I mean basis and dimension of $V/W$). But I am having no idea about the example written above.
I need help so that I can understand how to tackle such kind of problems. Thank you very much for your kind considerations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a general fact that $\dim V/W = \dim V - \dim W$ whenever $W$ is a subspace of a finite-dimensional space $V$. This follows from applying the rank-nullity theorem to the projection map $\pi : V \to V/W$. Thus, in your problem we have $\dim V/W = 3$. This means $V/W \cong (\mathbf{Z}/5\mathbf{Z})^{3}$ and thus $|V/W| = 5^3 = 125$.

Comment: Very nice and simple Daniel!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.  Could you just clear me how the isomorphism came? Why $V/W \cong (\mathbf{Z}/5\mathbf{Z})^{3}$

Comment: @Srijan Any two vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic. In this case $V/W$ and $(\mathbf{Z}/5\mathbf{Z})^3$ are both $3$-dimensional.

Comment: @DanielArreola Thank you so much for clearing my doubts.